# Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable identity not unique

Tags: zend-framework, authentication

For authentication on a website i use Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable. Everything work's fine, but Zend Framework only allow unique Identitys in the table.

As an identity i use the mail-address from my users. The problem is, that there are more items in the table with this mail-adress. User can delete there account and so i don't delete the whole row, i only change the status to -2 or something else. active user has the status 1.

i try to use it like so:

```
    $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'user', 'email', 'password', "? AND `status`='1'");
    $authAdapter->setIdentity($email);
    $authAdapter->setCredential($password);
```

But it doesn't work. If i delete the inactive user with the same mail-address, everything work's. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
$authAdapter->setIdentity($email);
$authAdapter->setCredential($password);

$select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where('status = 1');
```

**Try this full code**

```
 $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'user', 'email', 'password');
     $authAdapter->setIdentity($email);
    $authAdapter->setCredential($password);
    $select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
            $select->where('status = "1"');
```

OR

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());

       $authAdapter->setTableName('user')
            ->setIdentityColumn('email')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password');     

        $select = $authAdapter->getDbSelect();
        $select->where('status = "1"');
```

**[EDIT]**
OR

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db, 'user', 'email', 'password');
         $authAdapter->setIdentity($email);
        $authAdapter->setCredential($password);
$authAdapter->setCredentialTreatment('? and status = "1"');
```

FYI: [zend.auth.adapter.dbtable](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.html#zend.auth.adapter.dbtable.advanced.advanced_usage)

Comment: Hm doesn't work. If i var_dump the select, like so: var_dump($select->__toString()); i get an empty string. And every auth is true, even if i use a wrong password...

Comment: I tried both options but the don't work. The $select-var is empty. I read somewhere, that i have to write my own class for such auth-stuff with extend db-statements, but i don't think that... Anyways: I think you code-snippet don't work or i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I have added another way. Don't know which version you are using? try to provide some more info.